# routing is not after making build in react js web application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I've created one application in React js. Everything is working fine in development mode, but after making build routing is not working properly.

**My package.json file code**

```
{ "homepage": "http://localhost/hositng/react/",
    "private": true,
    "entry": {
         "index": "./index.js"
     },
}
```

**My routes file code**

```
const Routes = () => (
<BrowserRouter basename="http://localhost/hositng/react" >
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>);
```

After react build command, When I am hitting "http://localhost/hositng/react/" url

1. It's should go to login page but it is going to home page
2. And when click conact us page link it is going to Contact page url is getting change.

   it should go to this url "http://localhost/hositng/react/contact"
   but
   it is going to "http://localhost/contact" this url

But when I refresh the browser "http://localhost/contact" with this url blank page is coming

Answer (score 0):

Routes defined in Switch looks fine. I have used it and it works.
I will suggest using relative path in basename property instead of absolute path.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/hositng/react" >
```

For more information about it [BrowserRouter doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md#basename-string)

Comment: I already tried this one but it's not working for me.

Note :
Normally it's working for me but i am creating optimized build using npm run build command after that I facing this probleam with compiler code.

One more thing I running this compiler code  in my localhost under xammp. it there any probleam ?